# How can I set additional F# compiler flags when compiling with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, f#

I am writing an F# library that targets the .NET Framework 3.5 with Visual Studio 2012. I would like to use the [--standalone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233171.aspx) compiler flag so that the library contains all of the types needed to run by itself.

How can I set my F# project to compile with this flag with resorting to compiling with the command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add other compiler flags in the "Other flags" section of the project's properties.

[image: Screenshot of project properties]

Comment: Doh! That's a better answer than mine! I totally didn't see that textbox.